# xmlperformance ios5

Tags: iphone, xml, xml-parsing, sax

Using the apple example xmlperformance on ios5 does not seem to purge the memory and when parsing a file which is around 8MB seems to retain the memory in instruments.

What can i do to release this?

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746224/how-to-efficiently-parsing-large-xml-files-on-ios-in-order-to-store-the-content) could be helpful.